# MySQL error when altering table to Fulltext

Tags: mysql, database, full-text-search

I get an error `#1283 - Column 'title' cannot be part of FULLTEXT index` when I try to include the columns I want to alter via FULLTEXT in my database.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD FULLTEXT (`firstname`, `lastname`, `title`, `description`)
```

I'm not understanding why this error shows or how to go about in fixing this problem. Would be grateful for any ideas or tips.

Comment: What's the data type of `title` column?

Comment: The data type is text for title and description. Varchar for firstname and lastname @YogendraSingh

Comment: The storage engine is InnoDB @GregD

Comment: No, its InnoDB @YogendraSingh

Comment: That is the problem. Please refer the [**documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html). `Full-text indexes can be used **only with MyISAM tables**, and can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.`

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the default. It is MyISAM @YogendraSingh

Comment: @Octavius: Please refer the [Full Text limitations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-restrictions.html) and see if any apply in your case.

Comment: Please see my answer to your problem.

Comment: I already have my engine set to MYISAM I was looking at my default earlier when I answered the question @GregD

Comment: @Octavius Did you check the limitations? Does any apply?

Comment: Still reading through them @YogendraSingh

Comment: Got it! All my collations weren't the same @YogendraSingh.

Comment: @Octavius: Good you found it!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **NOTE**: This post applies to old version of MySQL.  Starting from
> version 5.6, `INNODB` supports `FULLTEXT` index and the below code should not be used.  Leaving the original answer for reference.

`FULLTEXT` index works only on `MyISAM` tables, not on `InnoDB`.  You can check what storage enging you use by typing:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE users;
```

then, you could `ALTER` the table to use `MyISAM` engine using this command:

```
ALTER TABLE users ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it.  Glad you found the solution!

Comment: Starting from Mysql 5.6, INNODB now supports FULLTEXT INDEX. Now I also ran into this issue when adding FULLTEXT to a table of mine and ran into multiple issues.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Mysql 5.6, INNODB now supports FULLTEXT INDEX. Now I also ran into this issue when adding FULLTEXT to a table of mine and ran into multiple issues.

1. you need to insure your ibdata1 file is set to autoextend. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html
2. I was running out of diskspace. While mysql alters a table, mysql uses tmp data and memory to do so. You need to make sure your tmp dir in you cnf file is pointing to a directory with enough space. Also, since it uses memory, it will use your Virtual Memory. Meaning your OS drive needs to have enough space. If this is not an option, create a tmp duplicate tmp table and alter that table with the fulltext and right an INSERT INTO `table` SELECT * FROM og_table

Answer (score 0):

If your table is **InnoDB** then you can not use it. And need to drop it.

You can also refer to limitations of InnoDB @ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Answer (score 0):

INNODB supports FULLTEXT INDEX since Mysql 5.6

To avoid errors "Column * cannot be part of FULLTEXT index"
check TEXT INCODING of your columns ;) It must be the same.